# Adding/Removing a dropdown option based on selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying this for a while now, searched everywhere here and on other sites.

I found some sort of a solution here http://jsfiddle.net/zszqs/

but when I try it on my code, on my actual page, it just doesn't work. It does in the example website tho, if I change all the code to mine.

```
<input name="documenttype" type="radio" required id="dType1" value="Pro-Forma">Pro-Forma
<input name="documenttype" type="radio" required id="dType2" value="Invoice">Invoice

<select name="paymentmethod" required id="paymentmethod">
<option value="" default selected>Select...</option>
<option value="TT">Online Bank Transfer</option>
<option value="PP">PayPal</option>
<option value="CC">Credit Card</option>
</select>
```

basically I want to remove the Credit Card option when the radio Pro-Forma option is selected, or bring it back again if user changes radio to Invoice...

```
<script>
var option = '<option value="CC">Credit Card</option>';
$('input[name=documenttype]').change(function() {
    var $select = $("#paymentmethod");
    if (this.id == 'dType1') {
        $select.find("option[value='CC']").remove()
    } else if (!$select.find("option[value='CC']").length) {
        $select.append(option)
    }
})
</script>
```

I feel like I'm not charging the code on page load, or something like this.
I'm totally new to jquery so I may have missed like, I don't know, where to put the `<script>` (head or body?) or if I have to specify some onLoad option.

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: my code is the one you see.. the example code in the top link is what I want to reach

Comment: i only see half of it. if the issue is in the javascript part, i would like to see it as well please. meanwhile, make sure you 1) - link the jquery library as the code in the fiddle is in jquery. 2) put the code block in the body in the very end after all your elements, or in the head in an onLoad function

Comment: But that demo doesn't reflect same html as in question

Comment: i'm sorry here it is :(

Comment: Seems to work fine here https://jsfiddle.net/9opnvobg/

Comment: I'm guessing you forgot to wrap code in `document.ready` or have errors in browser console

Comment: @StefanoRestuccia you are most likely forgetting to link the jQuery files. in the fiddle, they are linked via the framework&extensions in the javascript settings, while on your website you must include the jQuery file manually

Comment: exactly, the code does work there, but not on my actual page, that's why I feel i'm putting in the wrong part of the HTML code

Comment: wrap it in `$(function() { /* your code */})` and open browser console to see if any errors are thrown

Comment: thanks charlietfl i'm totally new to jquery so i appreciate

Answer (score 1):

**script code with jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
            {
                $(".documenttype").click(function ()
                {
                        $("option[value='CC']").css("display", $('#dType1').is(":checked") ? "none" : "block");

                });
```

});

**HTML Code**

```
<input class="documenttype" name="documenttype" type="radio" required id="dType1" value="Pro-Forma">Pro-Forma
            <input class="documenttype" name="documenttype"  type="radio" required id="dType2" value="Invoice">Invoice**
            <select name="paymentmethod" required id="paymentmethod">
                <option value="" default selected>Select...</option>
                <option value="TT">Online Bank Transfer</option>
                <option value="PP">PayPal</option>
                <option value="CC">Credit Card</option>
            </select>
```